# Dropdown menu appears on right instead of underneath anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

If I'm floating an element left that I want to be the toggle of the dropdown, the dropdown appears on the left side. I'm trying to get it to go to the bottom.

This usually doesn't happen in the regular bootstrap so I'm a bit lost. Anyone have any suggestions?

[Here is a Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wu76eHXkJOBFihr6xsvp)

```
<div id="top-header" class="slide" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <div id="cornerBox"></div>
    <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
        <a id="logo" class="clearfix dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle><span>{{ "header" }}</span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
                <a href>{{choice}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>

    <div id="searchBar">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cornerBox { float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#3CC274; }

#top-header {
    position:absolute;
    height: 56px;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color:#24BD66;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.23);
}

#logo
{
    font-weight:400;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin:3px 0 0 15px;
    height:30px;
    font-size:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#searchBar { position:relative;width:68%;margin:0 auto;left:100px;border-radius:3px;height:35px;margin-top:7px;background-color:#5ECD8C;}
#searchBar div { float:left;width:50px;height:35px;text-align:center;line-height:35px;font-size:15px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why, but the float is the problem. Set the anchor `inline-block` instead.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iy2bsD8YpeQLuKOSPCpy?p=preview)**

(My personal policy is to try inline-block before floats in every case--floats tend to cause more problems than they solve.)

Comment: Plunkr link fixed. I'm unfamiliar with Plunkr (usually use JSFiddle) and didn't save it properly.

Comment: Same. Thanks for the update! Seems to work nicely... I'm really sorry man, but could you check my updated plunk in the question and maybe give me your 2 cents? I forgot to add an important part to the `#top-header`. `inline-block` doesn't seem to work nicely if I have another div trying to go to the right of my "header" text. I didn't think it would matter so I left it out :\

Comment: Seems like if you float the search bar right all is well. http://plnkr.co/edit/wAwKxhB5RC1IK6OaEpNO?p=preview

Comment: Don't necessarily want to have my search bar floating right. Kind of wanted it sitting on the left after my header which I think is the issue. Depending on the page, I'll have other things floating right on that bar.

Comment: Ok, but now we're off topic. I'm not exactly sure what you're after since you seem to be trying to center the search bar with `margin: 0 auto`. Have a look at this. http://plnkr.co/edit/M6A5YWqeJSUxG2s35WIG?p=preview

Comment: [This is what I see](http://i.imgur.com/UvLQtBL.png/). I just wanted it to act the same was as the plunk in my example but get that dropdown to appear on the bottom :(

Answer (score 0):

I modified the Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VlRogdXUjFKMScCMJQpV?p=preview) and it seems to be what you want.

```
        <div class="dropdown clearfix" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
            // Other Code
        </div>
```

The key changes:

1. Using div instead of span. Span is an inline-block element (it appears on the same line) and div is a block element (it appears on a new line)
2. Add the clearfix class. When using float, it prevents all objects from colliding with it (and therefore ruining our plan of getting div on a new line). The clearfix class corrects for floating elements.

Comment: The dropdown seems positioned relative to the page with this approach, rather than the anchor.

Comment: @isherwood Indeed, the dropdown-menu class seems to apply absolute positioning. But that's easy enough to fix. I wanted to focus on why it was showing on the same line

Comment: This is great! thank you Vlad for speaking for the span vs div. That totally makes sense. @isherwood is right though, due to content underneath that I don't have in the plunk, I would like to have it position to the anchor. Would you mind putting in your 2 cents about the easy fix you were talking about?

Comment: v2. http://plnkr.co/edit/u0hxlcsctss5GaHmU4ko?p=preview 
Key Changes: Removal of floating and relative positions (I find floating should be a last resort). Because of this, we are back to span for the element. Addition of display=inline-block for the corner box (I wanted to go to Span, but it would show up. I assume this has to do with how div/span fill "empty" space). Addition of position=absolute for the dropdown. The dropdown class applies "position=relative" which was a problem

Comment: Great work Vlad, this is awesome. I unfortunately forgot a crucial elemement in my `#top-header` which I updated in my original question. But it seems to be causing a bit more difficulty then I expected. If you find the time, [please let me know what you think](http://plnkr.co/edit/D4hecy8fk4X2s25d7w93)(updated plunk with addition).